# How to render a Razor template inside a custom TagHelper in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I am creating a custom HTML Tag Helper:

```
public class CustomTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
        public ModelExpression DataModel { get; set; }

        public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            string content = RazorRenderingService.Render("TemplateName", DataModel.Model);
            output.Content.SetContent(content);
        }
    }
```

**How to render a partial view programatically an get the rendered content as a string inside TagHelper.ProcessAsync ?**
Should I request the injection of an IHtmlHelper ?
Is it possible to get a reference to the razor engine ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is possible to request the injection of an IHtmlHelper in the custom TagHelper:

```
public class CustomTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private readonly IHtmlHelper html;

        [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
        public ModelExpression DataModel { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
        [ViewContext]
        public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

        public CustomTagHelper(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
        {
            html = htmlHelper;
        }
        public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            //Contextualize the html helper
            (html as IViewContextAware).Contextualize(ViewContext);

            var content = await html.PartialAsync("~/Views/path/to/TemplateName.cshtml", DataModel.Model);
            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(content);
        }
    }
```

The `IHtmlHelper` instance provided is not ready for use and it is necessary to contextualize it, hence the `(html as IViewContextAware).Contextualize(ViewContext);` statement.

The `IHtmlHelper.Partial` method can then be used to generate the template.

Credit goes to [frankabbruzzese](https://github.com/frankabbruzzese) for his comment on [Facility for rendering a partial template from a tag helper](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5504).

Comment: Is this considered bad practice? Should we be using IHtmlHelper in our TagHelpers?

Comment: @Dave actually it might be a bad practice since [View Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components) exist.

Answer (score 6):

Adding a small (and yet important) addition to Chedy's answer (which is the right one), This code can be used in a base class:

```
public class PartialTagHelperBase : TagHelper
{
    private IHtmlHelper                         m_HtmlHelper;

    public ShopStreetTagHelperBase(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        m_HtmlHelper = htmlHelper;
    }

    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    protected async Task<IHtmlContent> RenderPartial<T>(string partialName, T model)
    {
        (m_HtmlHelper as IViewContextAware).Contextualize(ViewContext);

        return await m_HtmlHelper.PartialAsync(partialName, model);
    }
}
```

So, inheriting `PartialTagHelperBase` can help rendering partial views in a very simple and effective way:

```
        IHtmlContent someContent = await RenderPartial<SomeModel>("_SomePartial", new SomeModel());

        output.PreContent.AppendHtml(someContent);
```