# Parse Html string with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an application which generates dynamic html code with asp.net core tag helpers like

```
   <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
   <input asp-for="Name" />
   <input asp-for="IsActive" />
```

I return this html code from the database into the controller, I need to parse it with Razor Engine of asp.net core and of course pass a model for the engine to get data from, How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40443258/3645638

Comment: this requires physical view file, I need something like it but takes content of the view not the view itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible way to solve this, is by creating a custom IFileProvider that access the database.

Here is a blog post that explains how, but it's a bit older:
https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/301/loading-asp-net-core-mvc-views-from-a-database-or-other-location

The current offical FileProvider docs are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.2

This would simulate a virtual file-system with the content from the database, those views can then be used like any cshtml file (e.g. as partial view)

Comment: The IFileProvider interface has a method return IFileInfo called GetFileInfo, how could I implement it without returning a physical file info?

Comment: It seams your idea is the right option I found this article explains how to do it https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/301/loading-asp-net-core-mvc-views-from-a-database-or-other-location

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a custom file provider which get the views from the database and this link explains it
https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/301/loading-asp-net-core-mvc-views-from-a-database-or-other-location

Answer (score -1):

Define a model

```
    public class Model {
       Id, Name...
    }
```

and

```
@Html.Raw(your html template)
```

Comment: He isn't looking for an option to display HTML code. He needs to parse it via the TagHelper.

Comment: Not exactly, I just need to parse it with razor to generate the html code from the templates no need to do it from Tag Helpers, for example Razor parse this 
   <input asp-for="Name" /> 
with a model contains Name="Mahmoud" into
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="Mahmoud" />