# ViewComponents with children

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Can I use ViewComponents in a page like this.

```
<vc:parent-component>
     <some random html>
</parent-component>
```

when I try this it renders out only parent component.
In cshtml of parent-component I am looking for something like below

```
<h2>Parent component markup</h2>
@RenderChildren()??
<h2>Parent component markup end</h2>
```

So result will be

```
<h2>Parent component markup</h2>
@RenderChildren()
<h2>Parent component markup end</h2>
```

Answer (score 3):

Carlos solution of using TagHelper is awesome. I simplified his code down to a single class **RazorTagHelper**, (as I think it is a bit more aligned with the aspnetcore nomenclature.)

Here's the class

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Implements a tag helper as a Razor view as the template
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     uses convention that /TagHelpers/ has razor template based views for tags
    ///     For a folder /TagHelpers/Foo
    ///     * FooTagHelper.cs -> Defines the properties with HtmlAttribute on it (derived from ViewTagHelper)
    ///     * default.cshtml -> Defines the template with Model=>FooTagHelper
    /// </remarks>
    public class RazorTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private string _viewPath;

        public RazorTagHelper()
        {
            _viewPath = $"~/TagHelpers/{GetType().Namespace.Split('.').Last()}/Default.cshtml";
        }

        [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
        [ViewContext]
        public ViewContext? ViewContext { get; set; }

        public TagHelperContent? ChildContent { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            throw new Exception("Use ProcessAsync()");
        }

        public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            if (ViewContext is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ViewContext));
            }

            // get child content and capture it in our model so we can insert it in our output
            ChildContent = await output.GetChildContentAsync();

            IHtmlHelper? htmlHelper = ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IHtmlHelper>();
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(htmlHelper);

            (htmlHelper as IViewContextAware)!.Contextualize(ViewContext);
            var content = await htmlHelper.PartialAsync(_viewPath, this);

            output.TagName = null;
            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(content);
        }
    }
```

NOTE: I default the view path to a convention which is ~/TagHelpers/TagNameFolder/default.cshtml

A sample TagHelper then looks like this:
~/TagHelpers/Person/PersonTagHelper.cs

```
namespace Project1.TagHelpers.Person
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("Person")]
    public class PersonTagHelper : ViewTagHelper
    {
        [HtmlAttributeName]
        public string? Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [HtmlAttributeName]
        public string? ImageUrl { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

and template
~/TagHelpers/Person/default.cshtml

```html
@using Project1.TagHelpers.Person
@model PersonTagHelper
<h1>@Model.Name</h1>
<table>
   <tr>
     <th colspan=2>@Model.Name</th>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="@Model.ImageUrl"/></td>
    <td>@Model.ChildContent</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And of course this creates the **Person** tag which can be used in templates:

```html
<Person Name="Bob">
    <b>The thing about bob ...</b>
</Person>
```

Don't forget to include a `@addTagHelper` directive pointing to the assembly containing your taghelpers in your `_ViewImports.cshtml` file.

Again, thanks to Carlos and his ServerComponent library, it was very informative.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use random html inside `ViewComponent` tag helper as you did. May be your are considering `ViewComponent` tag helper as like as html element. Actually its not html element, rather its a razor code.

According to the [Invoking a view component as a Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2#invoking-a-view-component-as-a-tag-helper) documentation, Your `ViewComponent` tag helper should be like as follows

```
<vc:[view-component-name]
  parameter1="parameter1 value"
  parameter2="parameter2 value">
</vc:[view-component-name]>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use tag helpers when you need to pass children by having the following lines in your ProcessAsync function.

```
public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    var childContent = await output.GetChildContentAsync();
    output.Content.SetHtmlContent(fullContent);
}
```

They do have limitations, because inside tag helpers you don't instantly have access to razor templates, but there is a way to overcome that:

Check this other answer:

[How to render a Razor template inside a custom TagHelper in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40438054/how-to-render-a-razor-template-inside-a-custom-taghelper-in-asp-net-core)

and this for additional context:

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5504

When you combine these two approaches you can actually have a full server rendered component without using Blazor if you don't need to.

Edit:

Since giving this answer I've come up with a cleaner approach to doing this, you can check out this [repository](https://github.com/techgems/server-components).

Answer (score 0):

I have little bit changed and simplified [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73675946):

```cs
public class RandomViewTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    //For my use case I needed a condition based rendering so I used this.
    //If your use case if not like this skip this property and the condition
    //from `processasync` method 
    [HtmlAttributeName]
    public bool ShowChildContent { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    private DBConnection _connection;

    //Injecting any dependency like db connection if at all needed
    public RandomViewTagHelper(DBConnection connection)
    {
      _connection = connection;
    }

    public async override Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(ViewContext);

        IHtmlHelper htmlHelper = ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IHtmlHelper>();
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(htmlHelper);

        (htmlHelper as IViewContextAware)!.Contextualize(ViewContext);

        output.TagName = null;
        output.Content.Clear();

        if (ShowChildContent) 
        {
            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(await output.GetChildContentAsync());
        }
    }
}
```

The actual use case will be:

```html
<random-View show-child-content="@(<Condition-to-Show-or-hide>)">
   <-- Randome HTML -->
   <h1>Hello World</h1>
</random-view>
```

The above code is implemented with razor pages, ASP.NET Core and C#.