# Can you pass children to a .NET Core ViewComponent similar to what you do with a React component?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Is there any way to use an ASP.NET Core View Component like a React component?

For example, let's say you have a complex modal element defined as a view component, and want the inner template to be defined by the caller. Can you relay the inner markup to the view component like this?

```
<vc:modalbody>
  <div class="something">
    <h3>Some Title</h3>
  </div>
</vc:modalbody>
```

And then access it using something like `@RenderBody()` or `@Children()`?

This would be extremely useful.

Comment: The old ASP.NET User Control approach had something similar with _templates_, which allowed you to embed arbitrary markup similar to what you've included here, or even add multiple named subsections each with their own markup. It was incredibly useful. There's nothing comparable for View Components, but I'd love to see functionality like that implemented.

Comment: As an aside, here's a [similar, older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206787/viewcomponents-with-children).